# What's the Rails 4 equivalent of this routing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm trying to follow this: http://web.archive.org/web/20120315004343/http://webtempest.com/sortable-list-in-ruby-on-rails-3-almost-unobtrusive-jquery

And the routing done here is:

```
resources :books do
    post :sort, on: :collection
    # ruby 1.8 would go :on => :collection
end
```

What does `post :sort, on: :collection` mean here, and what would be the Rails 4 equivalent?

Comment: Tis valid here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resources :books` by itself gives you the CRUD routes.

`post :sort` by itself gives you a `POST` route `/sort` to the sort action.

`on: :collection` means that the action is for the whole collection (`books/sort`), unlike `member` which applies to each book (`books/:id/sort`). The `index` route is a collection route while `show` is a member route.

The syntax change from `:on => :collection` is exactly the same as `on: :collection` when using Ruby 1.9 or greater (as pointed out in the comments). I prefer to use the new syntax because it looks cleaner but it is not required. Both are valid in a Rails 4 app as long as you're using Ruby 1.9 or greater

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes

Comment: `on: collection` is not rails 4 syntax, it's Ruby >=1.9 syntax.